# Error mounting ntfs filesystem in linux?

Tags: centos, mount, ntfs-3g

[image]

I was trying to take a backup and messed up something and now I am getting the above error.

```
[msingh@centos boot]$ rpm -qa ntfs-3g ntfsprogs
ntfs-3g-2017.3.23-6.el7.x86_64
ntfsprogs-2017.3.23-6.el7.x86_64
[msingh@centos boot]$
```

How can I fix this ?

Edit as per suggestion given by Emmanuel:

```
[msingh@centos boot]$ file /dev/sdb1
/dev/sdb1: block special
[msingh@centos boot]$ sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sdb1 /mnt
NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb1': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sdb1' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
[msingh@centos boot]$
```

Comment: What did you mess up?

Comment: I was trying to use clonezilaa to take bacup and it did not work. I am not sure what exatly went wrong but after i rebooted i cannot mount the external hard drive

Comment: First, you can check the partition with `file /dev/sdb1` to see if it looks like an NTFS filesystem. You can also try mounting manually with `sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sdb1 /path/to/somewhere` Without knowing what went wrong, all you can do is troubleshoot.

Comment: `[msingh@centos boot]$ file /dev/sdb1
/dev/sdb1: block special` why does it shows block special, The error also shows worng fs type

Comment: Can i change the format to NTFS without destroying the data or copy the data somewhere else

Comment: There is something wrong with the filesystem, because i can see the data with testdisk also this helped a bit https://askubuntu.com/questions/47700/fix-corrupt-ntfs-partition-without-windows, now the error is gone but i cannot access the files yet

Comment: Mosty likely your NTFS superblock is damaged. AFIK, there's no open-source tool to repair the NTFS superblock, so you'll need to run a filesystem check from Windows. But before doing anything else with the drive I recommend taking a raw backup, with a tool such as `dd`, so that in the event things go from bad to worse you'll be able to go back to where you started. Regarding clonezilla, you said the backup did not work. How do you know it did not work?